# How to get content of the post request file POSTMAN

Tags: postman

I have a problem with sending files to some API. When I do it via my server some pdf files send correctly but some not. But when I send the same pdf via POSTMAN everything works just fine. I am not sure what is the reason (probably POSTMAN encodes it into base64 but from my server, I send it in binary - just a guess). Is there a way to get the sent request file content from postman so that I can imitate it and compare with the request on my server?

Comment: Have you checked that they are all entered correctly in the formdata request?

Comment: Yes, it's sent in a form-data request. The odd thing is that the file server receives file returns request.files.count = 1 for the POSTMAN file but when I sent it from my server is returned 0